# How to create a parameter in a PostgreSQL function with multiple values in it?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a function in PostgreSQL where I need to create a parameter and pass multiple values within it.

For example, I have a table named `group` which has 2 fields: `group_ck` and `groupid`. `groupid` has values like:

```
(abc,def,lsm,fed,sedd,erer,dlojn)
```

and `group_ck` is a sequence no.

Now I need to build a function and pass `groupid` values.  I know in sql we can define:

```
@group in=('abc','def','lsm','fed','sedd','erer','dlojn')
```

But in PostgreSQL, it doesn't work like this way. Can any one help me and provide an example on how I can  pass multiple values in a parameter?

Comment: Pass it as an array?: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array as parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function(params text[])
```

Then you are able to check it inside the function with something like

```
my_value = ANY(params)
```

(`params` should be your `groupid`)

Comment: thanks , so here is what i did and its throwing an error.DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS  abc (CHARACTER);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  abc (,p_grgr_id CHARACTER)
RETURNS  VOID
AS
$$
declare 
l_GRGR_ID CHARACTER (100);
 
if  coalesce(trim(p_grgr_id), '') = '' THE
 l_grgr_id= grgr_id from group where grgr_id like 'PEND%' and grgr_id= all(array[PENDD,PENDL,PENDC,PENDM,PENDF]);
 else
l_grgr_id:= p_grgr_id; 

end if;

raise info 'l_grgr_id: %', l_grgr_id; error says :column "pendd" does not exist

Comment: In your comment are many syntax errors. Please use a fiddle to demonstrate your problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/